# The profile session of kde konsole dosn't accept edit

Tags: linux, kde, konsole

I am using linux arch. I installed the KDE **konsole** as usual, but when I save the console settings it does not save.
I changed the default session to another session, but when you open the konsole, I must choose the other session each time.

```
uname -a
Linux arch 5.13.13-arch1-1
```

What's the solution?
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The profile is saved, each time with a new name, but just don't get loaded. You can load them by
*'Settings' > 'Switch Profile' > {Profile you want to use}*

To make the change permanent, i.e, loading a customised profile all the time, you need to set it as default. That is also simple
*'Settings' > 'Manage Profiles...' > Select you prefered profile and click 'Set as Default'*

Comment: I tried to make it from 1 to 9 as a default but it dosn't successed , but it dosn't work , recently the problem resolved after update and upgrade the system.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix the problem by making one of the profiles a default, but the problem still exists.

Recently the problem was permanently resolved after updating and upgrading my system like below:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```